# Getting duplicate values in Drop down list in JavaScript AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to show multiple selected values in drop down list coming from database. My drop down list is dependent on another drop down list.

**My JS code is:**

```
var cityName = <?= json_encode($cityName); ?>;
var area_name = document.getElementById('area_name').value;
$.ajax({
  'url': '<?= base_url('utility/cityByArea'); ?>',
  'type': 'POST',
  'dataType': 'JSON',
  'data': {
    area_name : area_name
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $('#city_name').find('option').not(':first').remove();
    $.each(response, function(index, data) {
      for(var i = 0; i < cityName.length; i++) {
        $('#city_name').append('<option value="' +data['city_id_primary']+ '" ' +(cityName[i] == data['city_id_primary'] ? 'selected' : '')+ '>' +data['city_name']+ '</option>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I'm getting correct selected values in drop down list, but the values in list is repeated.

I'm getting database value using php codeigniter code `var cityName = <?= json_encode($cityName); ?>;` in array form.

[image]

This is the `console.log(cityName);` output.

[image]

I'm getting output in drop down list.

Need to show single values.

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what values you are getting in `cityName`?

Comment: @Justcode please check my question, I just edit that.

Comment: `success: function(response) {` can you replace it with `success: function(response) { $('#city_name').empty() `

Comment: @Justcode, No its not working

Comment: Its very difficult to reproduce your problem , can you create demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code is outputting every city `cityName.length` times, because you're doing the append() operation inside both of your loops.

If you want to set multiple options as selected based on what's in the cityname list, then all you need to do is split the bit where you check for a match in the cityName list away from the bit where you append the option to the dropdown.

The logic is quite simple:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#city_name').find('option').not(':first').remove();

    //loop through each possible option
    $.each(response, function(index, data) {
      var selected = false; //boolean variable to store whether the option value matches any existing city, or not
      //loop through the existing cities
      for(var i = 0; i < cityName.length; i++) {
        if (cityName[i] == data['city_id_primary']) {
          selected = true; //we have a match
          break; //no need to carry on checking, so stop the loop
        }
      }

      //now append the option to the dropdown (once!) and set its selected attribute according to the value of the "selected" boolean.
      $('#city_name').append('<option value="' +data['city_id_primary']+ '" ' +(selected === true ? 'selected' : '')+ '>' +data['city_name']+ '</option>');
    });
  }
```

P.S. There's probably a "neater" way to write that using some jQuery array functions but that's the simplest version to understand.

Answer (score -2):

Change logic of 2 each functons:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cityName.length; i++) {
    $.each(response, function (index, data) {
        $('#city_name').append('<option value="' + data['city_id_primary'] + '" ' + (cityName[i] == data['city_id_primary'] ? ' selected ' : '') + '>' + data['city_name'] + '</option>');
    });
}
```

Comment: all you've done is swap the two loops. It won't stop the option value from being printed too many times.